# Hide link text from background image

Tags: text, hyperlink, background, hide

For example:

```
<div id="slideshow-nav">

... ...

<a href="#">Example</a>

... ...

</div>
```

In CSS, I have

```
#slideshow-nav a {
background: url(url-to-image) no-repeat;
color:#fff;
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

My object is to hide the text ("Example") and only display the background. However, I still want the link click-able.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#slideshow-nav a {
background: url(url-to-image) no-repeat;
color:#fff;
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;
text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

Will that work?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. I figured out another way to do it anyway. I put SPAN class on "Example" and set the visibility property of the SPAN to invisible.